# Place Symbol Above Character Outside of Math Mode

Tags: symbols

I am trying to place a text critical symbol ° (Unicode 00B0) above a Hebrew letter.

[image]

Here is part of the sentence:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\HE}[1]%
   {{\fontspec[Script=Hebrew]{SBL BibLit}\small\RL{#1}}}

\begin{document}

"The evidence from Qumran \HE{ל°אכל} is ambiguous...."

\end{document}
```

I have attached a photo to show the desired output.

[image: Desired output]

Comment: The input you have given has brackets, whereas in the expected output, they are absent. Can you elaborate? Can't read Hebrew, but from what I see in the output with standard fonts it seems that placing the circle above the N-like character is not the default, instead by default it is placed next to it. Do you mean whenever you input that Unicode (uni00B0) symbol, you expect it to be placed above the preceding character and not next to it?

Comment: Also, it is better if you use fonts available in the TeX distribution for minimal examples so that everyone can test. I don't have SBL BibLit. I have used NewCM for testing.

Comment: ` א\char"030A  `  Use a combining diacritic  U+030A

Comment: `\RL` is not defined in this example